# Multiple nth-last-child does't work as expected. Why?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS applied to it:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
}

ul {
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

ul > li {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 1%;
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(3) {
    background: #727272;
}
```

You can see the same in the fiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/peckinga/cj49hcrr/)**.

Now the following selector:

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(3) {
        background: #727272;
    }
```

Seems to be selecting the first element in the last row, I am not quite understanding how ?

Also

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):last-child {
        background: #727272;
    }
```

Does't work. Why ?

I would infact expect the following selector to select the first element on the last row:

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(1) {
        background: #727272;
    }
```

So what exactly am i misinterpreting here , Why does multiple `nth-child` selection not work the way i expect it to ?

**How i am trying to achieve:**
Select the first element in the last row .. i believe i have already acheived that , just don't know how it works.

Comment: Why `ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(3)` works is because the `:nth-last-child(3)` selects the 3rd element from the end, which happens to be 1st on the last row (and the `:nth-child(3n + 1)` target every 3rd start from the 1st, which again covers the first on the last row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This..

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(1) {
        background: #727272;
    }
```

does not work because it doesn't meet **both** conditions.

It's not `:nth-last-child(1)` AND `:nth-child(3n+1)` so it isn't selected.

This works

```
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(3) {
        background: #727272;
    }
```

becuasie it IS both `li:nth-child(3n + 1)` AND `:nth-last-child(3)`.

However, the fact that it selects the first element in the last row is **purely** coincidental.

CSS cannot detect layout. it has no idea that this is in a row at all. CSS selects **elements** and nothing else.

Comment: for some weird reason , i was thinking `:nth-child(3n + 1)` creates a collection and then i just do `nth-last-child(1)` , to select the last element in the collection , but i guess i was mistaken .. thats not how css works !